# How to improve extremely slow page load time on a 23MB web page full of SVGs?

Tags: html, performance, html5, load-time, svg

I have a webpage that is full of inline-SVG around 140+ inline SVGs! Just the HTML file size is 23MB, plus there is external CSS and JavaScript loading, though that is roughly only around 30KB. The real deal is the HTML file itself with thousands of lines of code mostly consisting of SVGs.

My webpage takes 2-3 minutes to load up on my (probably) average internet, how can I reduce the loading time while especially reducing the file size of the HTML file? I don't think using separate SVG files for the images would be any better because that would take even more time to load because of separate HTTP requests.

Is there any way for me to shorten the loading time from the current 2-3 minutes to under 5 seconds?

A small screenshot from the Networks panel in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129846/discussion-on-question-by-syed-mohammad-sannan-how-to-improve-extremely-slow-pag).

Comment: Depending on page layout and tech stack, you could use something like intersection-observer to selectively load the elements on the page

Comment: @Joe I have no idea at all what that is, I am gonna look it up, though, please give me some useful links to that as well If you have any. :D

Comment: What are the reasons for needing SVG?   This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The reason I thought using inline-SVG would be better was that a lot of PNG images might have been larger and size and would also cause many  HTTP requests (I did not know about lazy loading at that time).

Comment: Well, I resisted the urge lol... but still that's an XY, because you could have asked about that.  Always remember any problem you have, a million web designers have also had, and some of them are the people who design web standards.  They have spent 25 years optimizing browsers and altering web standards to solve problems just like that.  Never assume they didn't :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica lol yea it makes sense, I just ain't that much knowledgeable about this stuff, and btw you can downvote If you sincerely think this is an invalid question, rules should be followed :D no hard feelings.

Comment: I didn't.  Just learn the secret of the XY problem and you'll solve problems more easily!  Point being, you're not alone, you have lots of help!

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan Having a bunch of PNG icons would be better than using SVGs in this case, for a number of reasons. The PNG files would have been smaller in size than the SVG files, not larger. The HTTP requests concern is also unfounded, since PNG files can be inlined like SVGs can (though inlining would still be unnecessary and possibly detrimental on the whole). It seems to me like you made several incorrect assumptions coming into this question. I am glad the thread helped you anyways, though!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes you are correct, I made several incorrect assumptions but your answer turned out to be super-helpful for me and by the way a quick progress note here, now the webpage takes 7 seconds to load :D

Comment: Are they "static" svg's? Do they have to be inline? Can they be served from a CDN? How much of the load time is rendering? SVG's are generally not images until they are rendered.

Comment: @mckenzm I am not sure what you meant by CDN, mind elaborating?

Comment: @mckenzm Content Delivery Network, so they are not being served from your server. A CNAME entry for SVG.hostname say.

Comment: @mckenzm Oh I searched about it, would it be faster than using my own servers?

Comment: Are the SVGs static or is there anything dynamic about them (I.e. are they computed on the fly, like a chart based on data from a database for instance)?

Comment: @jcaron The SVGs are static in my case.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From what you've stated in the comments (now chat), I understand that you cannot reduce the size of these SVG files, you cannot replace them with thumbnails (e.g. small png files), and you cannot split them up onto multiple pages. In other words you are stuck with a web page that has 23MB worth of SVG files on it, and there's no way to change that.

That leaves you with only a few options left:

1. Make sure your server is properly compressing these files using `gzip` or `brotli` compression. You can check whether your server is properly compressing these files by [following this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18834602/2234742). SVGs are highly compressible, so this is a critical step. This alone could improve loading time by over 50%, if your server is not already doing this.
2. Make sure these SVG files are properly optimized and minified, using something like [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) (and [SVGOMG gui](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)). This could save maybe another 20-40%.
3. Consider linking the SVG files externally by using `img` tags, and use the [`loading: lazy` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading) on them. Then, at least the loading of the images will be deferred until the user scrolls down the page. (If, as you stated in the comments, your images are not initially visible in the viewport but are later shown dynamically by JavaScript, `loading: lazy` should still prevent them from loading until they are viewed, because it "Defers loading the image until it reaches a calculated distance from the viewport, as defined by the browser." Alternatively, you can modify your JavaScript to prevent the SVG tag from loading in at all until the script is triggered.)

If you link the SVG files externally by using `img` tags, that also has the added benefit of letting your HTML load to completion before the SVG files begin loading in. So parts of your HTML that are located below the SVG embeds in the document, like the footer, will load in before the SVGs finish.

To answer your concern about external SVG files generating separate HTTP requests that increase load time, this is not something you should need to worry about if your server supports HTTP/2 (so follow [this Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164719/2234742) to double check that it's enabled). If so, all requests will be multiplexed over a single TCP connection.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly gzip or brotli compression are? Also, can you tell me how using external SVG from the `img` tags be more helpful? because as far as my knowledge goes that would get us more HTTP requests and increase the loading time even more, right? Another thing, will `loading: lazy` work on a non-scrollable page? Because all those icons come on different popups and button clicks, the page doesn't really scroll at any point.

Comment: Also, sorry for being annoying but I am a beginner, but how does compression on inline-SVG work? Since I don't have any SVG files they are all inline inside the HTML code.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan Gzip and brotli compression are settings that you can enable in your server software (Apache, nginx, or your CDN). It compresses files on the server before it sends them to the browser. You'll want to [check that your web page requests are being served using gzip or brotli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18834602/2234742).

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan As far as compression of inline SVG, since in that case the SVGs are an embedded part of the HTML code, you would just want to make sure the HTML page that contains them is being compressed properly.

Comment: Aam, may I ask how to check If my server supports HTTP/2 since I am a total newbie at this server-related stuff. Btw I am on HostGator's shared hosting hatchling 2000 with Cpanel hosting, not sure If it supports It or not but let me try to know how to check it.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan I've added a link to my answer for how to check if your server has HTTP/2 enabled.

Comment: Can you break up the amount of SVGs across several pages? Like 10 to a page, then link to the next page?

Comment: @Steve It's a single-page-web-app, It has different popups based on the buttons you click like If you click on Admin Tools you will get a popup that contains clickable SVG icons such as Inventory, Library, Audit, etc.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yea most of them have h2 protocol except for the SVG images most of them have data protocol.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan The "data" protocol is just telling you that they're inline rather than separate files / HTTP requests. If you've decided to keep them inline, then the important thing to check is the 23MB of HTML - if that one's compressed, then the SVGs inlined within it are compressed. If you do decide to separate the SVGs out into external SVG files, then you'll want to check that the HTTP requests to those SVG files are also served with HTTP/2 and either gzip or brotli.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister hey I just checked the files in network tab and to my surprise some of the files already have the `"content-encoding: gzip"` except the images. I mean all my external CSS and JavaScript files have the `"content-encoding: gzip"` but any sort of images don't. Like the 3 of external SVGs I am loading and 2 png images I am loading both don't have the `"content-encoding: gzip"` message. Is this ok?

Comment: https://compress-or-die.com/svg <--- I use a lot. 

Christoph also has a nice api - https://compress-or-die.com/developers

Comment: @MikeCiffone Can I paste inline-SVG code into it as well?

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan As far as images go, most image formats such as `png` and `jpg` come already-compressed, so it's fine and even desirable that your server doesn't try to recompress those with gzip. SVG is an exception though because it is an uncompressed image format due to being text-based. If your server is not applying gzip to your externally linked `.svg` files, you will want to configure it to do that before you consider making the rest of the SVGs external, if that's the path you choose to go.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I see, though I think that converting all the inline-SVGs to external would be quite a time-consuming process, is there any work-around that, or any way to implement lazy-loading with the inline-SVGs?

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan Lazy-loading is not possible with inline SVGs. The browser starts downloading the HTML document, and doesn't stop until it reaches the end. If you don't have `.svg` files of all the images that are currently inlined, that's a bit rough. You would probably want to write a script to batch extract them from the HTML file, but that's beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Ok, I would appreciate it if you could share any links as to how one could achieve such a script in JavaScript. Though, thanks for helping anyways.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan I would use Python's [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), personally. I'd have it find each inlined SVG in the document and save it as a sequentially numbered (or named) `.svg` file.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Thank you so so much mate! I owe you an ice cream If we ever meet in real life.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan "It's a single-page-web-app, It has different popups based on the buttons you click" - Just because it's a SPA doesn't necessarily mean everything needs to be downloaded from the get go (although this may be difficult to refactor after the fact). External SVGs can also take advantage of persistent caching that inline images cannot.

Comment: @MrWhite Oh, I see.

Answer (score 24):

> I don't think using separate SVG files for the images would be any better because that would take even more time to load because of separate HTTP requests.

Efficient handling of linked images is something that browsers are specifically designed to do well. By inlining 23 MB of data in the HTML, you're blocking those optimizations.

If you split the icons to individual files, then the browser will cache individual icons and avoid redownloading them when the same icon is used repeatedly, on the same page load and on separate page loads. The browser will also be able to display the full text of the page before receiving all the images, which will improve the user experience.

Also, your SVGs are overcomplex for rendering at typical icon size. 23 MB for 140 images is an average of 168 kB per image. How big are they displayed? A small icon, 32×32, at 3 bytes per pixel is 3 kB *even as a completely uncompressed **raw bitmap***. A larger icon, 128×128, at 3 bytes per pixel, is a 48 kB raw bitmap. And uncompressed is the most pessimistic scenario to compare against. The point is, your SVGs contain more detail than you can possibly see at icon size. If you prerender them to PNGs, it will look identical but be dramatically smaller and lighter.

If you have the option to change the icons, you could also experiment with a different icon style. The current vogue is a flat iconographic shape with one or two colors, which happens to compress much smaller than a glossy gradient skeuomorphic icon. Changing the entire icon style is probably not necessary to fix your current performance problem, but if you needed to support very slow connections, it would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, It's all clear now. I even managed to reduce the loading time to 40 seconds by far :D because of you guys' answers